# Remove empty space when visible property is set to false using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I'm having a DropdownList and when its Selected Value is changed (for ex: 0 ) I need to set the visible property of a Panel to True and the visible property of another Panel to False.

and when another Value is selected I need to do Vice Versa Using JAVASCRIPT.

I'm currently achieving this but the space remains as it is. How can i remove the spaces also.

can anyone help me??

I'm attaching the code also.

```
function visible(val) {

    var ddl = document.getElementById("ddl_IDProof");
    var selectedFilterType = drpFilterType.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selectedFilterType == "0") {

        document.getElementById("pnl1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("pnl2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("pnl1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("pnl2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `display` instead of `visibility`.
This will hide the entire element:

```
    // Show pnl1 (maybe you have to use inline or inline-block insdead of block)
    document.getElementById("pnl1").style.display = "block";
    // Hide pnl2
    document.getElementById("pnl2").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: How can i set display of "pnl1" to none by default??

Comment: Inline style `<div id="pnl1" style="display:none">` or CSS `#pnl1 { display:none}` or JS Onload

Comment: style="display:none" is not working. If I use this the pnl1 is permanently not being displayed. I need to display again by using the above function

Comment: If I use this, the the Ajax RequiredFieldValidator is stopping me that `text not Entered` when used for a textbox. Can you Help Me?

Comment: @KrishnaThota as this is a new problem you should just open a new question about Ajax RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: Behaviour was the same as setting Visible to true/false for me :(

Comment: Further to my comment last year, I resolved it by setting Display to None/Block for the Table cell holding the controls concerned, rather than the controls themselves. ;)