# Ajax RequiredFieldValidator popping when display of a textbox is changed using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, requiredfieldvalidator

> **Issue:**
> Issue is due to "ValidatorCalloutExtender" which fires even when the RequiredFieldValidator is disabled using javascript  ValidatorEnable(val, enabled) Method.
>
> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How not to trigger RequiredFieldValidator on hidden field (TextBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710342/how-not-to-trigger-requiredfieldvalidator-on-hidden-field-textbox)

Please Refer this Question First.

[Remove empty space when visible property is set to false using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004234/remove-empty-space-when-visible-property-is-set-to-false-using-javascript)

In the above Question my empty space problem is solved but Another problem started to bug me.

I used the `.style.display = "block";` and `.style.display = "none";` properties to a textbox which has Ajax `RequiredFieldValidator`. When the Style is `block`, the TextBox is Displayed and when it is Empty The `RequiredFieldValidator` is popping. Until not this is Fine.

But when the TextBox Display Style is set to `"none"`,the `RequiredFieldValidator` is popping on the top left corner of the page and not allowing postback.

Can you Help me??

Here is the JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OtherProof(val) {
    // or use this both works
    //var ProofType = document.getElementById("ddl_IDProof");
    //var SelectedProofType = ProofType.options[ProofType.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val == "0") {
        document.getElementById("lbl_OtherProof").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tb_OtherProof").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("lbl_OtherProof").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tb_OtherProof").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the aspx Code

```
//Dropdown list whoch on selected i make the textbox Display and Disappear
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_IDProof" runat="server"
                 onchange="OtherProof(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
                  Width="155px">
                    <asp:ListItem>Driving License</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem >Voter Card</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Pan Card</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Other Proof</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

//Here are the label and Textbox which i make Display and Disappear
 <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_OtherProof" runat="server" Text="Other Proof" Font-Size="13px" style="display:none"></asp:Label></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_OtherProof" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="30" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="tb_OtherProof" FilterType="UppercaseLetters,LowercaseLetters,Custom" ValidChars=" "></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Req_OtherProof" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Proof Name is Mandatory" ControlToValidate="tb_OtherProof" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender7" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Req_OtherProof" 
                     CssClass="customCalloutStyle">
                    </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td>
```

Comment: Post the code that you are using.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal I posted the Code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **ValidatorEnable(val, enable)**

Takes a client-validator and a Boolean value. Enables or disables a client validator. Being disabled will stop it from evaluating and it will always appear valid.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function disableValidation() {
   var val = document.getElementById('Req_OtherProof');
   ValidatorEnable(val, false);
   if (document.getElementById("ValidatorCalloutExtender7_popupTable") != null) {
      document.getElementById("ValidatorCalloutExtender7_popupTable").style.display = "none";
   }
  }

    function OtherProof(val) {
    // or use this both works
    //var ProofType = document.getElementById("ddl_IDProof");
    //var SelectedProofType = ProofType.options[ProofType.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val == "0") {
        document.getElementById("lbl_OtherProof").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tb_OtherProof").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("lbl_OtherProof").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tb_OtherProof").style.display = "none";
        disableValidation();
    }
 }
    </script>
```

Comment: Its not working.. please check this link.[link](http://i.imgur.com/Vvcrl.png)

Comment: Here are The Links for aspx and cs files - [ASPX file](http://www.mediafire.com/?yd5g14z1xhtsp3g), [aspx.cs File](http://www.mediafire.com/?u8lrris79eepzqw)

Comment: @KrishnaThota Check my updated answer. You have to hide the "ValidatorCalloutExtender" popupTable.

Comment: How can we run the function `disableValidation()` on page startup??

Comment: Thank You It worked... O placed the Function in body onload to run the function on startup `<body onload="disableValidation();">`. Thankyou Verymuch