# How to remove extra space for hyperlink when Eval returns null?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, hyperlink

I have this Hyperlink:

```
    <asp:Hyperlink ID="LinkID" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("filename","~/Download.aspx?file={0}") %>' Visible='<%# !Eval("filename").Equals(DBNull.Value)%>' Text="Download file"></asp:Hyperlink>
```

If I add style="display:none" in there, then it disappears all the time. I only want the space to be freed when my condition for Visible is false.

Comment: If **Visible** is false, **a tag** won't even render to browser. What kind of extra space? Could you elaborate more or upload the screenshot?

Comment: visible false hides the content but does not treat it as it's not there, so there is still an extra space. display:none gets rid of the extra space but I can't figure out a way to make it conditional upon my eval.

Comment: So.. you're saying that even when the <a> tag is not rendered (meaning the visible property equals false) you still get a space in your rendered HTML?

Comment: If that's the case you should check the HTML that get's rendered and see what is it that's adding the extra space cause the <a> tag doesn't seem to be the culprit in your example.

Comment: Yes. As explained in this other question, visible=false will still leave an extra space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004234/remove-empty-space-when-visible-property-is-set-to-false-using-javascript

Setting 'display' to none seems to hide it but I can't figure out how to do so for my condition.

Comment: That's CSS visibility property, it's NOT the same as .NET Visible property. When a .NET control visible property is set to false the element does not get rendered in the resulting HTML.

Comment: Could you add to your question the code that is next to this hyperlink control?

Comment: @user3808188 You are confused with **Server Side Visible** attribute and **javascript visibility**. **Visible="false" means HTML tag will never render to browser** *although it might still be in ViewState*. Please upload the rendered HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your HyperLink in a server div tag (div with runat="server") and bind the visible of the div to your condition as shown below:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" visible='<%# !Eval("filename").Equals(DBNull.Value)%>'>
    <asp:Hyperlink ID="LinkID" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("filename","~/Download.aspx?file={0}") %>' Visible='<%# !Eval("filename").Equals(DBNull.Value)%>' Text="Download file"></asp:Hyperlink>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Eval("filename")` is a string? In that case it's value would be simply `null` or `""`.

`Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("filename"))%>'`

To be sure, you could print `<%#Eval("filename").GetType().FullName%>` and check what's it type, if it throws an exception that means that `Eval("filename")` is `null`.

Comment: Visible is working, the control becomes invisible(as in I can't see it) but there is still a blank space where it would be. I'm trying to get rid of that space.